# SQL Server if condition based on date

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I need help with, giving the if exists and if not exists condition.

I want to write an if condition, based on date, such that, if any row exists in table1 on current date `TARGET_DT` for a particular job, then do some action
else do other action.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME 
          WHERE TARGET_DT = CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 101) AND JOBID = @OPENJOB)         
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM COD_BLU_INVENTORY WITH(NOLOCK) 
       WHERE (JOBID = @JOB AND STATUS = 'A' AND TARGETDT = CONVERT(DATETIME, @TARGETDT, 101))) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO COD_BLU_INVENTORY(JOBID, TARGETDT, CARRYOVER, FRESHVOL, TOTALVOL, STATUS, UPDATEDBY, UPDATEDT, OPENINGVOL) 
        VALUES(@JOB, @TARGETDT, @CARRYOVERVOL, @FRESHVOL, @TOTALVOL, 'A', @EMPCODE, GETDATE(), @CARRYOVERVOL)

        SELECT '1'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        SELECT'0'
    END
END             
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME 
                   WHERE TARGET_DT = CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 101) 
                     AND TARGET_DT < CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 101) 
                     AND JOBID = @OPENJOB)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME(TARGET_DT, JOBID, OPENING_COUNT, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DT, PRE_ASSIGNEDCOUNT) 
    VALUES(@OPENTARDT, @OPENJOB, @OPENCNT, @OPENEMPCODE, GETDATE(), @PREOPENCNT)

    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM COD_BLU_INVENTORY WITH(NOLOCK) 
        WHERE (JOBID = @JOB AND STATUS = 'A' 
               AND TARGETDT = CONVERT(DATETIME, @TARGETDT, 101))) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO COD_BLU_INVENTORY(JOBID, TARGETDT, CARRYOVER, FRESHVOL, TOTALVOL, STATUS, UPDATEDBY, UPDATEDT, OPENINGVOL) 
        VALUES(@JOB, @TARGETDT, @CARRYOVERVOL, @FRESHVOL, @TOTALVOL, 'A', @EMPCODE, GETDATE(), @CARRYOVERVOL)

        SELECT '1'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        SELECT '0'
    END
END
```

but the problem is that if the `TARGET_DT` is given as future date, it executes the else condition, I want it to execute the if condition, the above is the code which I tired. Any help in solving this will be appreciated. Please help.

Comment: You want the `IF` part to be executed when the `TARGET_DT` is greater than `CURRENTDATE`(Future date)..??

Comment: Ya jibin, plus I want to check if any row exists in current date, and execute the if condition

Comment: I have posted an answer,check it and let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: well, itsems it doesn't return any rows

Comment: You want to insert the data into `COD_BLU_INVENTORY` when `TARGET_DT` is greater than `CURRENTDATE`??

Comment: yes jibin, I want to insert into COD_BLU_INVENTORY when TARGET_DT is greater than CURRENTDATE.

Comment: Updated my answer, check and let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: You got any problem with that query?

Answer (score 1):

```
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME WHERE ((TARGET_DT=CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),101) OR TARGET_DT>CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),101)) AND JOBID=@OPENJOB))          
        BEGIN
            IF(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM COD_BLU_INVENTORY WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (JOBID=@JOB AND STATUS='A' AND (TARGET_DT=CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),101) OR TARGET_DT>CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),101))))=0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO COD_BLU_INVENTORY(JOBID,TARGETDT,CARRYOVER,FRESHVOL,TOTALVOL,STATUS,UPDATEDBY,UPDATEDT,OPENINGVOL) 
                    VALUES(@JOB,@TARGETDT,@CARRYOVERVOL,@FRESHVOL,@TOTALVOL,'A',@EMPCODE,GETDATE(),@CARRYOVERVOL)
                    SELECT '1'
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN 
                    SELECT'0'
                END
            END             
     ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME WHERE ((TARGET_DT=CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),101) OR TARGET_DT<CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),101)) AND JOBID=@OPENJOB))
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO COD_BLU_OPENING_VOLUME(TARGET_DT,JOBID,OPENING_COUNT,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DT,PRE_ASSIGNEDCOUNT) 
            VALUES(@OPENTARDT,@OPENJOB,@OPENCNT,@OPENEMPCODE,GETDATE(),@PREOPENCNT)

            IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM COD_BLU_INVENTORY WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (JOBID=@JOB AND STATUS='A' AND TARGETDT = CONVERT(DATETIME,@TARGETDT,101)))=0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO COD_BLU_INVENTORY(JOBID,TARGETDT,CARRYOVER,FRESHVOL,TOTALVOL,STATUS,UPDATEDBY,UPDATEDT,OPENINGVOL) 
                    VALUES(@JOB,@TARGETDT,@CARRYOVERVOL,@FRESHVOL,@TOTALVOL,'A',@EMPCODE,GETDATE(),@CARRYOVERVOL)
                    SELECT '1'
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN 
                    SELECT'0'
                END
        END
    END
```

Comment: @rohini Can you share the test data and your expected result??